# How to stop Javascript from calling function multiple times when game is restarted

Tags: javascript, function

I am currently making a simple game called the simon game. It works pretty fine until the game is restarted. It calls on the function handler() multiple times. I tried to clear out the array with a function called startOver(). But I think the only problem is that it calls on the handler function multiple times. I don't understand why. Is there a way to clear out a function? or just a way to fix it? Here is my code:

```
let buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
let gamePattern = []
let level = 1;
let userClickedPattern = []
let currentLevel = gamePattern.length
let started = false

document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
    if (!started){
        if (event.key=="a"){
            nextSequence();
            handler();
       
            started = true
        }
    }
})


function checker(){
    if(userClickedPattern[currentLevel]===gamePattern[currentLevel]){
        if(userClickedPattern.length===gamePattern.length){
            level++;
            userClickedPattern =[];
            setTimeout(nextSequence, 1000)
        }
    }
    else if(userClickedPattern[currentLevel]!=gamePattern[currentLevel]){
        document.querySelector("h1").innerText = "Game Over. Press 'B' key to start again";
        let error1 = new Audio("sounds/wrong.mp3");
        error1.play()
        document.querySelector("body").classList.add("game-over")
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("game-over")
        }, 200)
        startOver();
    }
}

function nextSequence(){
    let randomChosenColor = buttonColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
    let sound1 = new Audio("sounds/"+randomChosenColor+".mp3");
    sound1.play()
    gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor)
    document.querySelector("h1").innerText = "Level "+(level);
    //STYLE
    document.querySelector("#"+randomChosenColor).classList.add("pressed");
    setTimeout(function (){document.querySelector("#"+randomChosenColor).classList.remove("pressed")
    }, 200)
  
}

function handler(){
    for(let i = 0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length; i++){
        document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            let userChosenColor = this.getAttribute("id");
            userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor)
            //SOUND
            let sound1 = new Audio("sounds/"+userChosenColor+".mp3");
            sound1.play()
            //STYLE
            document.querySelector("#"+userChosenColor).classList.add("pressed");
            setTimeout(function () 
                {document.querySelector("#"+userChosenColor).classList.remove("pressed")
            }, 200)
            checker();      
            console.log(gamePattern);
            console.log(userClickedPattern);     
        })      
    }
}


function startOver(){
    gamePattern = [];
    userClickedPattern = [];
    level = 1;    
    started = false

}
```

I know my code is pretty ugly, I'm still very new to coding.

Comment: Id wager the issue is related to the key being held down for more than one "tick", thus calling it multiple times until the key is released. You may be able to solve this with debouncing. Good resource for me was this: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it appears that every time the user types a key, you run `handler()` which then adds event listeners to every button. You probably only want to do that once.

Comment: Adding to existing comments, your flag, "started" isn't going to help. JavaScript is inherently asynchronous, so every time "a" is pressed you will get another thread with a new instance of the flag.

Comment: Will you also provide your html and css as a runnable code snippet (there's a button to create one on the toolbar when you edit your question)? I would make it a lot easier to tell what's going on if we could interact with your game.

Comment: @UncaAlby By design JavaScript is single threaded to prevent the scenario you describe. JavaScript event handlers will **not** run concurrently **nor** be provided with separate "instances" of variable bindings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plot twist! `handler` isn't being called multiple times... you've registered `"click"` events on your `.btn`s but you're not removing the event listener in `startOver`, resulting in the `click` seeming to fire multiple times.

Here's how you fix it:

1. Your `click` handler function cannot be an [anonymous function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions#The_function_expression_function_expression) because we'll need to reference it again later.
2. You need to call `Element.removeEventListener` for each of your `.btn` elements from inside of `startOver`.

Instead of this:

```js
function handler(){
    for(let i = 0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length; i++){
        document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
            let userChosenColor = this.getAttribute("id");
            userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor)
            //SOUND
            let sound1 = new Audio("sounds/"+userChosenColor+".mp3");
            sound1.play()
            //STYLE
            document.querySelector("#"+userChosenColor).classList.add("pressed");
            setTimeout(function () 
                {document.querySelector("#"+userChosenColor).classList.remove("pressed")
            }, 200)
            checker();      
            console.log(gamePattern);
            console.log(userClickedPattern);     
        })      
    }
}
```

We'll write this:

```js
// This was inside `addEventListener('click', [it was here])` before.
function handler() {
  let userChosenColor = this.getAttribute('id')
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor)
  //SOUND
  let sound1 = new Audio('sounds/' + userChosenColor + '.mp3')
  sound1.play()
  //STYLE
  document.querySelector('#' + userChosenColor).classList.add('pressed')
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector('#' + userChosenColor).classList.remove('pressed')
  }, 200)
  checker()
  console.log(gamePattern)
  console.log(userClickedPattern)
}

function registerHandlers() {
  // This used to be inside of the `handler` function.
  for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.btn').length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.btn')[i].addEventListener('click', handler)
  }
}
```

And we'll change your `"keydown"` listener to use the new `registerHandlers` function instead of `handler`:

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (!started) {
    if (event.key == 'a') {
      nextSequence()
      registerHandlers()

      started = true
    }
  }
})
```

And finally, we'll clean up the event listeners in `startOver`:

```js
function startOver() {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.btn').length; i++) {
    // Get rid of the old click listeners
    document.querySelectorAll('.btn')[i].removeEventListener('click', handler)
  }
  gamePattern = []
  userClickedPattern = []
  level = 1
  started = false
}
```

#### All together now!

Here's the complete code. You should be able to paste this in and have it work as expected. Other, yet-to-be found bugs, notwithstanding.

```js
let buttonColors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow']
let gamePattern = []
let level = 1
let userClickedPattern = []
let currentLevel = gamePattern.length
let started = false

document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (!started) {
    if (event.key == 'a') {
      nextSequence()
      registerHandlers()

      started = true
    }
  }
})

function checker() {
  if (userClickedPattern[currentLevel] === gamePattern[currentLevel]) {
    if (userClickedPattern.length === gamePattern.length) {
      level++
      userClickedPattern = []
      setTimeout(nextSequence, 1000)
    }
  } else if (userClickedPattern[currentLevel] != gamePattern[currentLevel]) {
    document.querySelector('h1').innerText =
      "Game Over. Press 'B' key to start again"
    let error1 = new Audio('sounds/wrong.mp3')
    error1.play()
    document.querySelector('body').classList.add('game-over')
    setTimeout(function () {
      document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('game-over')
    }, 200)
    startOver()
  }
}

function nextSequence() {
  let randomChosenColor = buttonColors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]
  let sound1 = new Audio('sounds/' + randomChosenColor + '.mp3')
  sound1.play()
  gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor)
  document.querySelector('h1').innerText = 'Level ' + level
  //STYLE
  document.querySelector('#' + randomChosenColor).classList.add('pressed')
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector('#' + randomChosenColor).classList.remove('pressed')
  }, 200)
}

function registerHandlers() {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.btn').length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.btn')[i].addEventListener('click', handler)
  }
}

function handler() {
  let userChosenColor = this.getAttribute('id')
  userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor)
  //SOUND
  let sound1 = new Audio('sounds/' + userChosenColor + '.mp3')
  sound1.play()
  //STYLE
  document.querySelector('#' + userChosenColor).classList.add('pressed')
  setTimeout(function () {
    document.querySelector('#' + userChosenColor).classList.remove('pressed')
  }, 200)
  checker()
  console.log(gamePattern)
  console.log(userClickedPattern)
}

function startOver() {
  for (let i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('.btn').length; i++) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.btn')[i].removeEventListener('click', handler)
  }
  gamePattern = []
  userClickedPattern = []
  level = 1
  started = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So my hunch was right that it was calling the handler() function multiple times when restarted so what I did was that I added the event listeners to the entire document and just removed the function handler() so that I wouldn't have to call that function just to get the event listeners and it worked! Here is the code that I made that worked:

```
let buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"]
let gamePattern = []
let level = 1;
let userClickedPattern = []
let currentLevel = gamePattern.length
let started = false

document.addEventListener("keydown",function(event){
    if (!started){
        if (event.key=="a"){
            nextSequence();
            started = true
        }
    }
});

function checker(){
    if(userClickedPattern[currentLevel]===gamePattern[currentLevel]){
        if(userClickedPattern.length===gamePattern.length){
            level++;
            userClickedPattern =[];
            setTimeout(nextSequence, 1000)
        }
    }
    else if(userClickedPattern[currentLevel]!=gamePattern[currentLevel]){
        document.querySelector("h1").innerText = "Game Over. Press 'B' key to start again";
        let error1 = new Audio("sounds/wrong.mp3");
        error1.play()
        document.querySelector("body").classList.add("game-over")
        setTimeout(function(){
            document.querySelector("body").classList.remove("game-over")
        }, 200)
        startOver();
    }
}

    function nextSequence(){
        let randomChosenColor = buttonColors[Math.floor(Math.random()*4)];
        let sound1 = new Audio("sounds/"+randomChosenColor+".mp3");
        sound1.play()
        gamePattern.push(randomChosenColor)
        document.querySelector("h1").innerText = "Level "+(level);
        //STYLE
        document.querySelector("#"+randomChosenColor).classList.add("pressed");
        setTimeout(function (     {document.querySelector("#"+randomChosenColor).classList.remove("pressed")
        }, 200)
    
    }


for(let i = 0; i<document.querySelectorAll(".btn").length; i++){
    document.querySelectorAll(".btn")[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        let userChosenColor = this.getAttribute("id");
        userClickedPattern.push(userChosenColor)
        //SOUND
        let sound1 = new Audio("sounds/"+userChosenColor+".mp3");
        sound1.play()
        //STYLE
        document.querySelector("#"+userChosenColor).classList.add("pressed");
        setTimeout(function ()    {document.querySelector("#"+userChosenColor).classList.remove("pressed")
        }, 200)
        checker();      
        console.log(gamePattern);
        console.log(userClickedPattern);     
    })      
}
    
function startOver(){
    gamePattern = [];
    userClickedPattern = [];
    level = 1;    
    started = false;

}
```